# Good alternatives of comporting two subquery in the 'Where' clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have this schema:

```
CLUB(Name, Address, City)
TEAM(TeamName, club)
PLAYER(Badge, teamName)
MATCH(matchNumber, player1, player2, club, winner)
```

I need to make this query:

> For each club, find the number of players in that club that have won
>   at least two games.

I wrote this:

```
SELECT teamName
From TEAM t join Match m1 on t.club=m1.club
WHERE Q2 >= ALL Q1
```

Q1:

```
SELECT Count (Distinct winner)
FROM MATCH
WHERE match m join player p on m. winner=player.badge
GROUP BY teamName
```

Q2:

```
SELECT Count (distinct winner)
FROM match m2
WHERE m2.club=m1.club
```

I don’t know if it is correct, however I heard that using this form where I confront two counts is not the best. Why?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data and desired result would helpful.

Comment: Hi. You don't need count to find the clubs with sufficient . You just need a certain per-club grouping to have two rows with the same winner but different matches. This is a faq, which you would find via google if you phrased what you wanted clearly. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT club, COUNT(*) as PlayerCount
FROM (SELECT club, winner
      FROM match
      GROUP BY club, winner
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) a
GROUP BY club
```

The inner query should limit results to club/player combinations that have 2 or more wins, and the outer query will count the number of these players per club.

> I don’t know if it is correct, however I heard that using this form where I confront two counts is not the best. Why?

Comparing two count subqueries is fine if you need to, but a good rule of thumb is to hit each table as few times as possible.  Using multiple subqueries will end up hitting each table multiple times, and will *usually* result in longer execution times.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT t.club, COUNT(*)
FROM TEAM t
JOIN PLAYER p ON p.teamName = t.TeamName
JOIN (
    -- Won at least 2 matches.
    SELECT club, winner, COUNT(*) AS TheCount
    FROM MATCH
    GROUP BY club, winner
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) w ON w.winner = p.badge AND w.club = t.club
GROUP BY t.club
```